# Where is cout declared?

Tags: c++, terminology, cout, ostream

My computer science professor wants us to find the declaration of `cout`. I've compiled a simple Hello world program using g++ and the -E parameter. Here's what my hello.cpp looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string name="";

  cout << "Good morning! What's your name?";

  cin >> name;

  cout << "Hello " << name << ".\n";

  return 0; 

}
```

My compile command:

```
g++ -E hello.cpp > hello.p
```

In hello.p, I ran a search in VIM, like so:

```
:/cout
```

I see the following line:

```
extern ostream cout;
```

Is that the declaration of `cout`, and is `cout` an instance of the `ostream` class?

**Edit:**

What's the `wcout` declaration there for? If I recall correctly the letter "w" stands for "wide", but I don't know what implication that has. What is a `wcout` and a `wostream`?

Comment: I'd be willing to guess somewhere in the code that gets tacked on to your executable when you link against IOStream.

Comment: @Aslai - I've pulled out a line from that code. I want to know if that's it.

Comment: Try this: http://www.cplusplus.com/ - type `cout` into the search box.

Comment: Yes, cout is an instance of ostream class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed the declaration of `std::cout`, found inside the `<iostream>` header.

The relevant standard part can be found in `§27.4.1 [iostream.objects.overview]`:

> Header `<iostream>` synopsis

```
#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std {
  extern istream cin;
  extern ostream cout;
  extern ostream cerr;
  extern ostream clog;
  extern wistream wcin;
  extern wostream wcout;
  extern wostream wcerr;
  extern wostream wclog;
}
```

> p1 The header `<iostream>` declares objects that associate objects with the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in `<cstdio>` (27.9.2), and includes all the headers necessary to use these objects.

Comment: @Moshe: `wcout` is just a `basic_ostream` specialized on `wchar_t`, which means UTF-16 on Windows and UTF-8 on Linux IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that the declaration of cout, and is cout an instance of the ostream class?

Yes, that is the declaration of `std::cout` and yes it's an instance of `std::ostream`. It is declared `extern` so that the object is only created once even if the header is included in multiple translation units.

Comment: Don't forget the `namespace std { ... }` part. It's `std::ostream std::cout`, not `::ostream ::cout`.